# このHaskellプロジェクト(自作)をビルドしようとするとリンカがエラー吐きます

Tags: haskell

### 実行したコマンド

`$ git clone http://github.com/aiya000/ahs-diary.git`
`$ cd ahs-diary.git`
`$ git checkout -b tmp origin/tmp`
`$ stack build`

以上でリンカ(ld)がMain.oに対してのエラーを吐きます。

環境は
Ubuntu 15.04
stack 0.1.2.0
です。

拙い質問で申し訳ないのですが、Haskellに触れられず大変辛いものがあります。
どなたか助けてください…。

下記にエラーをそのまま記します。

```
ahs-diary-0.1.0.0: build
Building ahs-diary-0.1.0.0...
Preprocessing library ahs-diary-0.1.0.0...
In-place registering ahs-diary-0.1.0.0...
Preprocessing executable 'ahs-diary-exe' for ahs-diary-0.1.0.0...
Linking .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.18.1.5/build/ahs-diary-exe/ahs-diary-exe ...
.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.18.1.5/build/ahs-diary-exe/ahs-diary-exe-tmp/Main.o: 関数 `c7kI_info' 内:

(.text+0x54db):`ahszmdiaryzm0zi1zi0zi0_DiaryziNew_newDiary2_closure' に対する定義されていない参照です
.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.18.1.5/build/ahs-diary-exe/ahs-diary-exe-tmp/Main.o: 関数 `c6tH_info' 内:

(.text+0x6f):`ahszmdiaryzm0zi1zi0zi0_DiaryziNew_newDiary1_info' に対する定義されていない参照です
.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.18.1.5/build/ahs-diary-exe/ahs-diary-exe-tmp/Main.o: 関数 `c7kI_info' 内:

(.text+0x54e4):`ahszmdiaryzm0zi1zi0zi0_SystemziDiaryziIO_prompt1_info' に対する定義されていない参照です
.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.18.1.5/build/ahs-diary-exe/ahs-diary-exe-tmp/Main.o: 関数 `c7kI_info' 内:

(.text+0x54fb):`ahszmdiaryzm0zi1zi0zi0_DiaryziNew_newDiary1_info' に対する定義されていない参照です
.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.18.1.5/build/ahs-diary-exe/ahs-diary-exe-tmp/Main.o: 関数 `S6u7_srt' 内:

(.data+0xa10):`ahszmdiaryzm0zi1zi0zi0_DiaryziNew_newDiary1_closure' に対する定義されていない参照です
.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.18.1.5/build/ahs-diary-exe/ahs-diary-exe-tmp/Main.o: 関数 `S6u7_srt' 内:

(.data+0xc88):`ahszmdiaryzm0zi1zi0zi0_DiaryziNew_newDiary2_closure' に対する定義されていない参照です
.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.18.1.5/build/ahs-diary-exe/ahs-diary-exe-tmp/Main.o: 関数 `S6u7_srt' 内:

(.data+0xc90):`ahszmdiaryzm0zi1zi0zi0_SystemziDiaryziIO_prompt1_closure' に対する定義されていない参照です
.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.18.1.5/build/ahs-diary-exe/ahs-diary-exe-tmp/Main.o: 関数 `S6u7_srt' 内:

(.data+0xca0):`ahszmdiaryzm0zi1zi0zi0_DiaryziNew_newDiary1_closure' に対する定義されていない参照です
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

--  While building package ahs-diary-0.1.0.0 using:
      /home/aiya000/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-7.8.4/bin/runhaskell -package=Cabal-1.18.1.5 -clear-package-db -global-package-db -package-
db=/home/aiya000/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux/lts-2.19/7.8.4/pkgdb/ /tmp/stack6990/Setup.hs --builddir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.18
.1.5/ build
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
```

Comment: argusさん > 本当にありがとうございます、ビルドできました！！ Haskellは人類の希望です！！

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cabal ファイルの `exposed-modules` に、外部から参照される関数が含まれるモジュールを全て列挙する必要がある様です。

**ahs-diary/ahs-diary.cabal**

```
library
  hs-source-dirs:   src
  exposed-modules:  Diary.Edit, Diary.New, System.Diary.IO, Lib
```

以下、`Ubuntu 15.04/GHC 7.8.4/cabal-install 1.22.6.0/stack 0.1.2.0` での実行結果(の抜粋)です。

```
$ stack build
ahs-diary-0.1.0.0: configure
          :
Linking .stack-work/dist/i386-linux/Cabal-1.18.1.5/build/ahs-diary-exe/ahs-diary-exe ...
ahs-diary-0.1.0.0: install
            :
Installing executable(s) in ...
Registering ahs-diary-0.1.0.0...
```